# Can this problem be implemented in parallel in Cython with OpenMP?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmp, cython

I have parallalised some Cython code with OpenMP. **Once in a while**, the code computes wrong results.

I created a nearly minimal working example of my problem. "Nearly", because the frequency of the wrong results seem to depend on even the tiniest changes in code, thus, e.g. I kept the function pointers in.

The Cython code is

```
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, cdivision=True
# distutils: language = c++

import numpy as np

cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cimport numpy as np

cdef inline double estimator_matheron(const double f_diff) nogil:
    return f_diff * f_diff

ctypedef double (*_estimator_func)(const double) nogil

cdef inline void normalization_matheron(
    vector[double]& variogram,
    vector[long]& counts,
    const int variogram_len
):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(variogram_len):
        if counts[i] == 0:
            counts[i] = 1
        variogram[i] /= (2. * counts[i])

ctypedef void (*_normalization_func)(vector[double]&, vector[long]&, const int)


def test(const double[:] f):
    cdef _estimator_func estimator_func = estimator_matheron
    cdef _normalization_func normalization_func = normalization_matheron

    cdef int i_max = f.shape[0] - 1
    cdef int j_max = i_max + 1

    cdef vector[double] variogram_local, variogram
    cdef vector[long] counts_local, counts

    cdef int i, j

    with nogil, parallel():
        variogram_local.resize(j_max, 0.0)
        counts_local.resize(j_max, 0)

        for i in range(i_max):
            for j in range(1, j_max-i):
                counts_local[j] += 1
                variogram_local[j] += estimator_func(f[i] - f[i+j])

    normalization_func(variogram_local, counts_local, j_max)

    return np.asarray(variogram_local)
```

To test the code, I used this script:

```
import numpy as np
from cython_parallel import test

z = np.array(
    (41.2, 40.2, 39.7, 39.2, 40.1, 38.3, 39.1, 40.0, 41.1, 40.3),
    dtype=np.double,
)

print(test(z))
```

The result should be

```
[0.         0.49166667 0.7625     1.09071429 0.90166667 1.336
 0.9525     0.435      0.005      0.405     ]
```

This is what a wrong result typically looks like

```
[0.         0.44319444 0.75483871 1.09053571 0.90166667 1.336
 0.9525     0.435      0.005      0.405     ]
```

This code mainly sums up numbers into the the vector `variogram_local`. Most of the time, this code works, but without having made sufficient statistics, wrong results are produced maybe every 30th time. It always works, if I change the line `with nogil, parallel():` to `with nogil:`. It also always works, if I don't use the function pointers at all, like this:

```
    with nogil, parallel():
        variogram_local.resize(j_max, 0.0)
        counts_local.resize(j_max, 0)

        for i in range(i_max):
            for j in range(1, j_max-i):
                counts_local[j] += 1
                variogram_local[j] += (f[i] - f[i+j]) * (f[i] - f[i+j])

    for j in range(j_max):
        if counts_local[j] == 0:
            counts_local[j] = 1
        variogram_local[j] /= (2. * counts_local[j])

    return np.asarray(variogram_local)
```

The full code is tested on different platforms and these problems mainly occure on MacOS with clang, e.g.:

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/conda-forge/staged-recipes/builds/29018878

**EDIT**

Thanks to your input, I modified the code and with `num_threads=2` it works. But as soon as `num_threads>2` I get wrong results again. Do you think that, if Cython support for OpenMP would be perfect, my new code should work or am I still getting something wrong?
If this should be on Cython's side, I guess I will indeed implement the code in pure C++.

```
def test(const double[:] f):
    cdef int i_max = f.shape[0] - 1
    cdef int j_max = i_max + 1

    cdef vector[double] variogram_local, variogram
    cdef vector[long] counts_local, counts

    cdef int i, j, k

    variogram.resize(j_max, 0.0)
    counts.resize(j_max, 0)

    with nogil, parallel(num_threads=2):
        variogram_local = vector[double](j_max, 0.0)
        counts_local = vector[long)(j_max, 0)

        for i in prange(i_max):
            for j in range(1, j_max-i):
                counts_local[j] += 1
                variogram_local[j] += (f[i] - f[i+j]) * (f[i] - f[i+j])

        for k in range(j_max):
            counts[k] += counts_local[k]
            variogram[k] += variogram_local[k]

    for i in range(j_max):
        if counts[i] == 0:
            counts[i] = 1
        variogram[i] /= (2. * counts[i])

    return np.asarray(variogram)
```

Comment: Just in addition what @Zulan has said, you call `normalization_func` after the parallel section but with `*_local variables`, so if they were properly local then you'd get a nonsense result anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to their name, `variogram_local` and `counts_local` are not actually local. They are shared and all threads mess around with them in parallel, hence the undefined result.

Note that you don't actually share any work. It's just all threads doing the same thing - the whole serial task.

A somewhat sensible parallel version would look more like this:

```
variogram.resize(j_max, 0.0)
counts.resize(j_max, 0)

with nogil, parallel():
    for i in range(i_max):
        for j in prange(1, j_max-i):
            counts[j] += 1
            variogram[j] += estimator_func(f[i] - f[i+j])
```

The shared arrays are initialized outside and then the threads share the inner `j`-loop. Since no two threads will ever work on the same `j`, this is safe to do.

Now it may not be ideal to parallelize the inner loop. If you were to actually parallelize the outer loop, you would have to in fact make actual local variables and merge/reduce them afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer. Naively, I always thought that parallelisation with OpenMP was easy. From what I read, it might not even be possible to use the local variables this way in Cython at the moment. Do you have any further hint?

Comment: I suspect if you assign to `*_local` within the parallel block (e.g. `variogram_local = vector[double](j_max)`) it will become thread-local. However, because Cython makes these decision implicitly it's always hard to know what it's done without looking at the generated code. It's often better just to write the parallel loop in C/C++ where you can control these things yourself then call that from Cython

Comment: Assignments do in fact make variables thread local within `parallel()` blocks. However, you need to consider that these variables are not available after the `parallel()` block.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your modified code is that you have a race condition the section which adds up `counts_local` and `variogram_local`. You want this *in* the parallel block (so that you still have access to the thread-local variables) but you only want one thread at a time to be working on it. The easiest way is to put it in a `with gil:` block so that Python enforces the "one thread at a time":

```
with gil:
    for k in range(j_max):
        counts[k] += counts_local[k]
        variogram[k] += variogram_local[k]
```

This bit should hopefully be a quick task at the end, so shouldn't take too long.

If it were in C/C++ you'd probably use `#pragma openmp atomic` or `#pragma openmp critical` instead for the block. It's difficult to to this in Cython since their OpenMP support is quite basic, but you probably could abuse wrapped C macros to make the addition atomic.

---

Cython's OpenMP support is really geared around simple loops and scalar reductions. If you're doing more than that then it doesn't have the syntax to give you fine control of OpenMP and for this reason I'd tend to recommend writing your critical OpenMP functions in C or C++ (whichever you're more comfortable with).